# How do I still print logs to console while running ExUnit tests?

Tags: elixir, ex-unit

For debugging purposes during a failing integration test, I would like to still be able to see my application logs. Is there a command I can pass to the `mix test` task to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every mix project has a `config.exs` file. When mix starts, it loads this file. A common pattern in elixir is to define configs for different environments, like `test.exs`, `dev.exs`, `prod.exs`, etc, etc.

Many projects like Phoenix will generate these files for you in your `config` folder, and you'll see this line in your `config.exs` line:

```
import_config "#{Mix.env}.exs"
```

When you run `mix test` it sets `MIX_ENV` environment variable to "test" which means the import_config line loads your `test.exs` file.

So in order to set your logging level for just your tests, in your `test.exs` file you can write the following:

```
# Print only warnings and errors during test
config :logger, level: :warn
```

Comment: This answer explains nicely where to edit test config, but not how to edit it to show debug logs. See my answer for configuration that will enable logs in test.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show `IO.inspects` and other debug logs on `mix test`, change the following config:

1. In `config/test.exs`, find the following line:

```
# Print only warnings and errors during test
config :logger, level: :warn
```

2. Comment the previous line out and add the following config with the `compile_time_purge_matching` option:

```
config :logger,
  backends: [:console],
  compile_time_purge_matching: [
    [level_lower_than: :debug]
  ]
```

When you are finished debugging your tests, comment out the
`compile_time_purge_matching` config in step 2 and uncomment
your original `level: :warn` config to avoid messy test logs.

**Older Versions Note:** If you are on an older version of Elixir,
use the following deprecated config in place of `compile_time_purge_matching`:

```
config :logger,
  backends: [:console],
  compile_time_purge_level: :debug
```

`compile_time_purge_level: debug` will still work on Elixir 1.12 with deprecation warnings.